# Gradle implicit dependency warning for embed configuration

Tags: java, gradle

I am getting the message that execution optimizations have been disabled to ensure correctness. This is because I am embedding my library in my project, but the project does not depend on the library. I'm kind of confused as to why that is because my embed task extends the `java-library`'s `api` task and that depends on the given project, right?
To clarify any confusion, I have a [multi-project build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:creating_multi_project_builds)

In my project I have following configuration for my embed task:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
configurations {
    embedApi
}
dependencies {
    configurations.api.extendsFrom(configurations.embedApi)
}
jar {
    from {
        configurations.embedApi.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Warning message:

```
Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'mylibrary\build\libs\mylibrary.jar'. Reason: Task ':myproject:jar' uses this output of task ':mylibrary:jar' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
```

**EDIT**
I found putting this into myproject/build.gradle solves things:

```
jar {
    dependsOn(':mylibrary:jar')
}
```

but then the entire file looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    embedApi project(':mylibrary')
}
jar {
    dependsOn('mylibrary')
}
```

Even though it works it is still kind of ugly. I want to move the `jar` section into my root project where the configuration is defined so I do not have to make it dependent for every subproject
I'm also open for other embedding options, I just want my library embedded and the warning solved (preferably in a one-liner like `embedApi('<dependency>')`)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, was as simple as

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
configurations {
    embedApi
}
dependencies {
    configurations.api.extendsFrom(configurations.embedApi)
}
jar {
    dependsOn configurations.embedApi
    from {
        configurations.embedApi.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```